# Can I read the maxOccurs property for a segment from the stream being processed?

Tags: bean-io

I am trying to create a mapping file for a fixed length file that contains multiple repeating segments. Problem is, that more than one of these segments are repeated an indefinite number of times, which is not supported by beanio for flat files. I understand, that there is a good reason for this, as beanio can do only so much guesswork about how often a segment repeats.

However the number of repetitions for each segment is present in the file, at a position before the repeating segments occur, so I am trying to figure out whether there is a way to read that number from the stream and then populate the "minOccurs" and "maxOccurs" properties for the following segment with the correct value.
Basically my mapping file looks like:

```
<beanio>
  <stream name="employeeFile" format="fixedlength">
    <record name="record1" class="example.Record1">
      <field name="field1" length="10"/>
      <field name="field2" length="2"/>
      <field name="length1" length="2"/>
      <segment name="list1" collection="list" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" class="example.List1">
        ...
      </segment>
      <field name="length2" length="2"/>
      <segment name="list2" collection="list" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" class="example.List2">
        ...
      </segment>
    </record> 
  </stream>
</beanio>
```

I now need some way to use the value of fields length1 and length2 as "maxOccurs" property in the segments. I am fairly certain that there is no "official" way to get this behavior, but I have so far failed to come up with an even remotely elegant solution for this.

An idea I had was to create a procedure that loads the number of repetitions for each segment from the file and then doing a search-replace on the mapping file, before loading this in beanio, however this seems like a very complicated way of doing things.

Thanks,
 Sönke

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer myself. I was reading the beanio reference documentation for version 2.0, not 2.1 which introduced the feature I am looking for.

The reference document states:

> If a field repeats a fixed number of times based on a preceding field
>   in the same record, the occursRef attribute can be used to identify
>   the name of the controlling field. If the controlling field is not
>   bound to a separate property of its parent bean object, be sure to
>   specify ignore="true". The following mapping file shows how to
>   configure the accounts field occurrences to be dependent on the
>   numberOfAccounts field. If desired, minOccurs and maxOccurs may still
>   be specified to validate the referenced field occurrences value.

So one can use:

```
<field name="accounts" type="int" collection="list" occursRef="numberOfAccounts" />
```

to get the intended result.

I don't think this property works with xml streams, as it is not really needed here. I accidentally tried to add this in a mapping file and got an exception instead of a proper error message.